# wordmove Validating movefile section: production error This remote has not ssh nor ftp protocol defined

Tags: ssh, ftp, movefile

I'm newbie in [wordmove](https://github.com/welaika/wordmove).
I've created movefile.yml in my local server but doctor command says:

```
▬▬ ✓ Validating movefile section: production ▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬
    error | This remote has not ssh nor ftp protocol defined

▬▬ ✓ Validating movefile section: ssh ▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬
    error | This remote has not ssh nor ftp protocol defined
```

my remote server is hosted on godaddy and terminal ssh connection works perfectly.
Any suggests?

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong indentation of the `ssh` key. I got it because the doctor is considering `ssh` as a section (thus a root key in the YAML), so it should be like:

```
production:
  vhost:
  wordpress_path:
  [...]
ssh:
```

But `ssh` has to be nested inside `production`

```
production:
  vhost:
  wordpress_path:
  [...]
  ssh:
```

If that is the case, so the doctor is right: your `production` lacks of the `ssh` section.